# How to clean dusty screen protector?

Tags: dust

Hi I've messed new screen protector cause of lot of dust around. 
I tried shampoo to clean it and that's working but wait til it dry it gets dusty again. 
So how can I clean it?

Comment: One of the best things to use to clean a screen is a used fabric softener dryer sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to static electricity, dust will stick to plastic and plasticized materials more readily than in a static-free environment.

I would avoid the use of any detergent or soap as there is a good chance you can remove any coatings on the surface of the screen protector or that some of the "cleaner" will work its way under the protector to dissolve the adhesive holding the screen protector onto your screen.

You can remove the dust on your screen protector sheet with a slightly damp (not wet) cloth or lint-free wipe. **Avoid** using a dry one as the friction of the two materials against each other will CREATE more static which is counter-productive.

If you can also add moisture to your place to raise the relative humidity, the amount of environmental static will be lessened and your dust accumulation on your screen protector will be less too.

There are related questions and answers on this site about reducing static electricity which you can apply. A simple search should bring up a good suggestion for you.

Good luck.